# NaN error in ajax callback

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am getting a `NaN` error in my ajax callback function and can only think it has to do with an array in PHP. I have been trying to find ways to correct it but have come up against a brick wall.

What is supposed to happen is that PHP queries the database and if there are no results send a response to ajax and issue the error message. However, all I am getting is `NaN`. The error stems from the `success` code below.

I would be grateful if someone could point out my error.

PHP code:

```
$duplicates = array();

foreach ($boxnumber as $val) {
    if ($val != "") {
        mysql_select_db($database_logistor, $logistor);
        $sql = "SELECT custref FROM boxes WHERE custref='$val' and status = 'In'";
        $qry = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

        if (mysql_num_rows($qry) < 1) {
            $duplicates[] = '[ ' . $val . ' ]';
            $flag = 1;
        } else {
            $duplicates[] = $val;
        }
    }
}

//response array with status code and message
$response_array = array();
if (!empty($duplicates)) {
    if ($flag == 1) {
//set the response
        $response_array['status'] = 'error';
        $response_array['message'] = 'ERROR: ' . implode(',', $duplicates) . ' needs to be in the database to be retrived.';
    }
//if no errors
} else {

//set the response
    $response_array['status'] = 'success';
    $response_array['message'] = 'All items retrieved successfully';
    $response_array['info'] = ' You retrieved a total of: ' . $boxcount . ' boxes';
}

//send the response back
echo json_encode($response_array);
```

Relevant ajax:

```
$("#brtv-result").html(msg.message+msg.info);
```

jQuery code:

```
$(function() {

 $("#BRV_brtrv").submit(function() {

   var send = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "boxrtrv.php",
      cache: false,
      data: send,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(msg) {
       if( msg.status === 'error') {
          $("#brtv-result").fadeIn(1000).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
          $("#brtv-result").removeClass('error');
          $("#brtv-result").removeClass('success');
          $("#brtv-result").addClass(msg.status);
          $("#brtv-result").html(msg.message);
       }

       else {
          $("#brtv-result").fadeIn(2000).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
          $("#brtv-result").removeClass('error');
          $("#brtv-result").addClass('success');
          $("#brtv-result").addClass(msg.status);
          $("#brtv-result").html(msg.message+msg.info);
          //location.reload(true);
          //$('#brtv-result').addClass("result_msg").html("You have successfully retrieved: "+data.boxnumber).show(1000).delay(4000).fadeOut(4000);
          $("#BRV-brtrv-slider").val(0).slider("refresh");
          $("input[type='radio']").attr("checked",false).checkboxradio("refresh");
          var myselect = $("select#BRV-brtrv-department");
          myselect[0].selectedIndex = 0;
          myselect.selectmenu("refresh");
          var myselect = $("select#BRV-brtrv-address");
          myselect[0].selectedIndex = 0;
          myselect.selectmenu("refresh");
      }

     },
      error:function(){
         $("#brtv-result").show();
         $("#brtv-result").removeClass('success');
         $("#brtv-result").addClass('error');
         $("#brtv-result").html("There was an error submitting the form. Please try again.");
     }
   });
   return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: `NaN` definitely comes from JavaScript. Please show the complete snippet from where you issue the request.

Comment: @alenx, are you referring to the ajax or the jquery

Comment: It's not very clear exactly what this error looks like, but I bet it has something to do with how you make the ajax call from the page. One of your form fields probably is being computed by other JavaScript code (that you have not posted), and the computation is resulting in a NaN value instead of a good number.

Comment: Have you used Fiddler or some other proxy to see exactly what comes back from the server? Are msg.message and msg.info correct?

Comment: @eapscarello. fiddler has no online facility for php. thanks

Comment: @pointy. I am posting numbers and string. for example, item1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NaN` (pronounced nan, rhymes with man) only happens when you try to do an operation which requires a number operand. For example, when you try to `Number('man')` you'll get this error.

What you return from your PHP file, is simply an array which contains simply data. So, the problem is in your JavaScript. You have to send more parts of your JavaScript, so that we can see it thoroughly.

However, I recommend that you use Firebug and set a breakpint at the correct place (the callback function start), and check the stack trace of the calls to diagnose the problem.

Comment: It would also be useful to look at the actual HTTP request parameters (with Firebug), and see which parameter has a "NaN" value. The next step would be to find out *how* a form field got a "NaN" value.

Comment: saeed please see updated code in question. Actually the reason I said about array was before I added the else statement, it responded ok. So I guess it must be to do with the way is being sent? thanks

Comment: @pointy, this is using jquery mobile and for some strange reason does not display in FF.

Comment: saeed, is there an option in chrome to set breakpoints. If so I shall load that up and try. thanks

Comment: @bollo, of course, simply hit `F12` to bring up the development tools, then go to `Scripts` tab, then find your script from the list, then find your code, then where you want to place your breakpoint, simply click on the line number on the left side (you'll get a blue icon). Now the breakpoint is set.

Comment: saeed, I have set that but i do not know what I am looking for. Do I look in scope and if so, what do I need to check. thanks